# What am i doing wrong in creating and calling this simple class function?

Tags: python, function, class

```
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
    def vol(self):
        return width * height

w = int(input())
h = int(input())

obj = Rectangle(w, h)

obj.vol()
```

I get an error message saying 'width' is not defined?

Comment: please provide the complete code

Comment: You probably need to write `self.width` (instead of just `width`) since width is a variable of the instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have it return the object's width and height since it's a class method.
You can do this using "self" to reference the instance of the class

```
class SomeClass():

  def __init__(self, width, height):
     self.width = width
     self.height = height

  def vol(self):
     return self.width * self.height
```

Comment: also self in third and fourth lines

Comment: So what is the point of writing "self.width = width" and "self.height = height" in the init function if I then can't refer to it as just "width"?

Comment: @MuhammedJaseem if you are referring to the other 'width' and 'height' in the init function, they are in reference to the parameters of the init function and do not need self in front of them.

Comment: @snoopaloop because width and height could really mean anything. In the init method you are defining the instance's attributes with the self.something. You use self to show that it only applies to that instance of the class.

Comment: oh yaaaa my bad

Comment: @snoopaloop If I helped you out consider accepting this answer :)

Comment: It did. How do I do that, the check?